# Mocking promises and Timers in a recursive function with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to cover some code in a unit test (specifically, the code inside the catch block) and I believe it's failing due to memory leak errors probably due to timers that are not properly mocked.

Here's an example of the main code:

```
    const delay = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);

    const readCustomerStatus = async (retry = 2) => {

    let content = '';
    try{
      await delay;
      content = await fs.readFileSync(CUSTOMER_PATH,'utf8');
    }
    catch(error){
      while(retry > 0){
        readCustomerStatus(retry - 1);
      }
    }
    return content;
    }
```

And here's the unit test code:

```
    test('Should return error when readFileSync fails'),async()=>{

    fs.readFileSync = jest.fn()
    .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('readFileSync failed'))
    .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('readFileSync failed'));
    const customerStatusResult = await readCustomerStatus();
      expect(customerStatusResult).toThrow(‘readFileSync failed’);

    }
```

When I remove the recursive call from the main code, the unit test works. It looks like somehow the delay promise might be somehow affecting the test. I have also tried adding jest.useFakeTimers() in the beforeAll function but that doesn't seem to be helping either.

Comment: Why do you await readFileSync? The point of that method is it's the *synchronous* version. Also note that you should either recurse *or* iterate, retry's value never changes within each scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code has multiple issues, most of them related to the way you are (not) awaiting Promises.

When you create a `Promise` this way, it will start executing right away, and will be resolved only once:

```
// Timer starts right away, which I believe it is not what you wanted
const delay = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
```

So this is the behavior:

```
   await delay // Awaits `delay` Promise to be resolved.
               // Depending on when it started, might be less than 1 second
   await delay // This second invocation will be already resolved. 0 seconds delay.
```

Same is happening to your recursive version. You are awaiting that same `delay` Promise multiple times (on each recursion), so you are not actually pausing for 1 second on each iteration.

Here you have another issue:

```
    catch(error){
      while(retry > 0){
        readCustomerStatus(retry - 1); // issue: readCustomerStatus is async
      }
    }
```

In this line you are invoking an async function without await, so you are just creating a new unhandled Promise, and completing the execution of the first one with success (because you trapped the error and ignored it).

You also shouldn't use a `while` loop in your retries, because that will cause a never ending loop, since `retry` variable is local to each call. Replacing by an `if` will fix it.

Finally, you are missing to raise the original error if all retries failed (will show how to fix below).

I wouldn't recommend using recursion to handle retries, I think it makes the code less readable and also there is some unnecessary stack allocation. However, for educational purposes, let's fix this code:

```
const delay = (ms=1000)=>new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const readCustomerStatus = async (retry = 2) => {
    let content = '';
    try {
      // Notice we invoked function here to create a new Promise on each iteration
      await delay();
      content = await fs.readFileSync(CUSTOMER_PATH,'utf8');
    } catch(error) {
      if (retry > 0) {
        // it is important to use await here and assign the result to `content`
        content = await readCustomerStatus(retry - 1);
      } else {
        // This is our base case, so we just raise whatever error we found
        throw error;
      }
    }
    return content;
}
```